# Best practice for dynamic table creation plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, plugins, html-table

I'm working on a plugin that will dynamically create product tables and append them to divs (or whatever selectors call the plugin function). So far, it works as planned but the tables are generated by copying an HTML template that is hardcoded onto the view. My code is long so I'm not going to paste all of it but it is essentially like this (very generally and minus all the table logic functions):

(rowtemplate html)

```
$.fn.block = function(rows, maxrows) {
    var productRows = $(this);

    function createRows(rows) {
        var rowHTML = $('.rowtemplate').html();
        for(var i = 1; i < rows + 1; i++) {
            $('<tr class="productrow"></tr>').appendTo(productRows).append(rowHTML);
        } 
    }

    function createTable(rows) {
        createRows(rows)
        // bind table logic functions and other stuff
        ......
    }

    // bunch of other stuff, defining table logic functions

    createTable(rows, maxrows);
}
```

So basically when you say ("#div2").block(5, 10), the plugin takes in 5 as rows and 10 as max rows and pipes those into createTable which calls createRows and binds functions to create the table. This of course gets appended to #div2. The issue is that the createRows function works by using the rowtemplate html above (which I basically just made for testing purposes). This means the plugin is obviously not very portable if you have to bring the template with it every time. So I think there are three ways to implement the HTML:

1. Write the HTML template into the view every time the plugin is used (worst option IMO, for reasons I just stated)
2. Hardcode the HTML template into the plugin so that it just gets appended prior to table construction (only once)
3. Link to an external js file that appends it or link to an external html file that contains it (makes things cleaner but also adds external file dependency which is a pain and makes the plugin only usable with the external file)

I'm strongly leaning towards 2 but I don't know what other developers who have worked on similar projects have done, so I'd like to know if there is another option. I don't see how there could be because the HTML has to be in an external file, in the HTML part of the view or in the Javascript...so logically I can't think of an alternative but would welcome suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, that is a jQuery extension and not a plugin. if it were a plugin you would make the HTML another *option*, passed to the plugin, but provide a default template in the default options.

For your extension, you could do it like this (using a single options parameter):

```
$.fn.block = function(options) {
     // Get the options or use the defaults
     var html = options.html || "<div>my default html template</div>";
     var rows = options.rows || 5;
     var maxrows = options.maxrows || 10;
```

and call like this:

```
$(selector).block({rows: 2, cols: 10, html: "<div>etc</div>"});
```

**note:** All of the parameters are optional!

Another option is to pass a selector, that chooses the template from an element in the existing page, so it can be as complex as you like. Using a dummy script block (with unknown type so it is ignored) is great for this:

```
<script id="mythtml" type="text/template">
    <div>My template</div>
</script>
```

and call like this:

```
$(selector).block({rows: 2, cols: 10, html: "#myhtml"});
```

and use like this:

```
$.fn.block = function(options) {
     var html = $(options.html).html();
```

again this could use a default if you prefer:

```
$.fn.block = function(options) {
     var html = $(options.html).html() || "<div>my default html template</div>";
```

Or, combine both ideas:

```
$.fn.block = function(options) {
     // Get the options or use the defaults
     var html = $(options.html).html() || "<div>my default html template</div>";
```

The same code will work with a HTML string or a selector :)

Comment: Great idea! I don't think I'll be using the selector parameter method but it's cool to know that that option is available should I decide to modify the (soon-to-be) plugin in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @user3654575: Use them all together... It's all about having sensible fallback values.